# Rephrasing a Judicial Sentence

Tags: meaning

The Virginia attorney general said:" Courts would likely rule anti-LGBT discrimination is illegal under state law". The last part of the sentence beginning with **is** seems vague to me. So, can anyone rephrase the sentence, please?

Comment: @sumelic: I have said that the last part that begins with "is" makes it difficult for me to understand. Is there any kind of ellipsis in the sentence?

Comment: Oh, so the structure is what is difficult? It means the same thing as "Courts would likely rule that {anti-LGBT discrimination is illegal under state law}." In this context, "rule" means "decide that." The last part of the sentence is actually a clause starting with "anti-LGBT discrimination is."

Comment: Thanks sumelic. Misunderstanding the meaning of "rule" makes it difficult for me to get the  whole meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatives:

1. Courts would likely rule that discrimination is illegal.
   (unreduced relative pronoun)
2. Courts would likely rule that discrimination would be illegal.
   (keeping same tense throughout)
3. Courts would likely rule discrimination to be illegal.
   ('discrimination' raised-to-object; infinitive inherits the tense of 'would')
4. Courts would likely rule discrimination illegal.
   (reduced to object complement)